# Parse to Clevertap Transition

Tags: java, android, parsing, clevertap

I am trying to convert Parse to Clevertap in the application I'm working on. I have tried looking at https://blog.clevertap.com/transitioning-from-parse-push-notifications/ but haven't had much luck on what I'm trying to accomplish.

In the method that needs to be converted, I am wanting the user to have the ability to subscribe and unsubscribe from a channel using:

```
    private class AllPushClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private AppFeed mAppFeed;

    public AllPushClickListener(AppFeed appFeed) {
        mAppFeed = appFeed;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "subscribing to " + getPushChannelName(mAppFeed) + "_all");
        ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground(getPushChannelName(mAppFeed) + "_top");
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(getPushChannelName(mAppFeed) + "_all");
        mAppFeed.setPushNotificationsOn(true);
        mAppFeed.setReceiveTopNotifications(false);
        mAppFeed.setChannelName(getPushChannelName(mAppFeed) + "_all");

        hideNotificationButtons();
        mPushAllStoriesSelectedButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mPersistedFeedDaoHelper.createOrUpdate(mAppFeed);
    }
}
```

Not sure how to transition this into Clevertap.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Parse migration guide here - https://github.com/CleverTap/parse-migrate and, channels is discussed here - https://github.com/CleverTap/parse-migrate#managing-channels. Do write to support@clevertap.com if you need more help, or have any questions.